# "You do not have permission to access this content" error after inputting data into an HTML form

Tags: wordpress, php

I am working with an arts organization in my town and they recently migrated their civiCRM application (which is serving as a plugin to their wordpress website) from GoDaddy to InMotion.  We are having a problem with an HTML form on one of our pages that, when submitted, is throwing the following error string:

**You do not have permission to access this content**

the form has the following fields:

**"first name, middle name, last name, email, are you a robot?"**

in the civiCRM dashboard, I can look at the HTML markup for the page when I navigate in the following manner (menu clicks):

**administer > customize data and screens > profiles > "Add e-mail (this is the profile name) > HTML form snippet**.  But the HTML markup only has a huge number of links to various javascript files, which I assume are the scripts that are running the AJAX, asynchronous code that submits the form?  Since I can't submit a test record, I can't see whether the page is being redirected after submittal (e.g. - possibly running a **header()** command in PHP at the end of the POST script.  Can someone point me in the right direction in terms of what I should be looking for to fix this error?  As far as I was told, there aren't too many pages on our site that are erroring out.  I was only shown this one.  thanks guys!

an image of the error we're seeing can be seen here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17iuGObM7rPIJwgWQIPMMvhoVglHFM8YW/view?usp=sharing

We are running on the following platforms:

Wordpress: Ver 5.3
civiCRM: Ver 5.18.3
PHP: Ver 7.2

Comment: It will help folks track down the problem if you post anything of relevance from your CiviCRM logs. On WordPress, they are usually found in `wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog`

Comment: thank you for your response Christian.  I was not part of the solution, however it was fixed for many of the pages on which it was occurring.  However, later on I discovered that it was indeed occurring on a couple of other pages.  So I still need some help with this.  there are 3 log files in the directory you told me to look in.  they are named as in my next comment (this forum is saying my messages are too long)....

Comment: CiviCRM.93117e35eec0e390571f9236 (SIZE > 342 KB)
CiviCRM.f00e475b61a1b1adcfe92ffd (SIZE > 1 KB)
CiviCRM.f3e1f44ffa13a2f7fa12d1d1 (SIZE > 51 KB)

The page URL that is throwing the error when the form is submitted is: 
 http://artifactory.OurDomain.org/get-involved/volunteer/

and when the form is submitted, I am redirected to this URL:  https://OurDomain.com/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fuf%2Fgroup

Comment: I looked in each log file for the string "volunteer" but I found nothing.  I have no idea what to search for as I have no experience with reading civiCRM log files.  Can you guide me in this regard?  In the largest log file I do see a lot of entries that have the strings "PEAR.php", "DB_ERROR()" and "CORE" in them.  So I can identify the log somewhat, but other than the string "Volunteer" I don't know what else to search for.  thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your CiviCRM "WordPress Permissions" page to make sure everything is as it should be?